# Why is JPanel still painted?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, paint, paintcomponent

I am actually trying to create a JPanel, containing a bunch of ui elements for the user to manipulate the application. This panel is placed on top of Java3D scene. Therefore, I wanted the background of this JPanel to be transparent. Neither `panel.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0))` nor `popupPanel.setOpaque(false)` nor both calls made the panel background transparent. So I decided to sub-class JPanel and play with paintComponent. No effect. Then I tried paint. Nothing. Then I got confused. So I overwrote literally every method I know of, related to painting a JPanel and left each method body blanc (see below). When I run the application, I still get the panel. How can that be? I placed some System.out.println to be sure that the class is the right one, and is called. It is the right one. Despite all this missing code, the only difference to a normal JPanel is that the button is only painted if the mouse enters the button bounds. What am I missing?

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class TransparentPanel extends JPanel {

    protected Color bg = new Color(0,0,0,0);

    public TransparentPanel() {
        super();
        setOpaque(false);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) { }
    
    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.vendor"));
        System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
        for(Component c: getComponents()) {
            System.out.println(c.toString());
        }
    }
    
    @Override
    public void repaint(Rectangle r) {}
    
    @Override
    public void repaint(long tm,int x,int y,int width, int height) {}
    
    @Override
    protected void paintChildren(Graphics g) {}
    
    @Override
    protected void paintBorder(Graphics g) {}
    
    @Override
    public void paintImmediately(int x,int y,int width, int height) {}
    
    @Override
    public void paintImmediately(Rectangle r) {}

}
```

and

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.OverlayLayout;

public class OverlayoutTest extends JFrame {


    public OverlayoutTest() {
        super("Test");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(new Dimension(400, 300));

        add(createPanel());
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    private  JPanel createPanel() {
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(){
            @Override
            public boolean isOptimizedDrawingEnabled() {
                return false;
            }
        };
        mainPanel.setLayout(new OverlayLayout(mainPanel));

        
        JComponent popupPanel = createPopupPanel();
        popupPanel.setAlignmentX(1.0f);
        popupPanel.setAlignmentY(0.0f);
        mainPanel.add(popupPanel);

        SpatialView view = new SpatialView(null);       // A class extending JPanel containing a Java3D Canvas3D in a BorderLayout
        mainPanel.add(view);
        view.addScaledPlanetModel();

        return mainPanel;
    }
    
    

    private JComponent createPopupPanel() {
        TransparentPanel popupPanel = new TransparentPanel();
//      popupPanel.setBackground(new Color(0,0,0,0));
//      popupPanel.setOpaque(false);
        popupPanel.setMaximumSize(new Dimension(250, 300));
        

        JButton button = new JButton("HI there!");   // the button does nothing but is nice to spot
        button.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        popupPanel.add(button );

        return popupPanel;
    }


    
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new OverlayoutTest();
    }
}
```

I am using OpenJDK version "11" 2018-09-25, build 11+28 and Java3D 1.7.0

Comment: Swing was not designed to paint with transparent colors.  You can paint a background on a `JPanel` with Swing components.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the problem (or I didn't understand it), but I had used an blue `JPanel` as background instead of the `SpatialView`. I can only see the button - [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z0wWv.png), the `TransparentPanel` is transparent; maybe the `SpatialView` does not recognize that the panel is transparent and does not paint the area that would be *obscured* behind the panel

Comment: It seems to be an issue with Java3D. I replaced the SpatialView with another "normal" JPanel from another project and turned the popupPanel into a normal JPanel again. It works with setBackground and setOpaque as expected. So yes, Swing can definitely paint with transparent colors. But Java3D interferes somehow and prevents the effect. I'll repost as Java3D issue. Thank you.